# Requirement for extracting all public group Members in a sheet

Tags: public-group

I have a requirement to export all the active public group members.

Currently we are doing select all on the screen and then extracting in an excel sheet. Then we are filtering out inactive members from the sheet.

Is there a better way to export them either via report or some browser plugins?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **'Dataloader'** to extract the Public Group Members from **'GroupMembers'** object. You will need to provide an additional query to export only those members who are active. The query will be like below.

```
Select Id, GroupId, UserorGroupId From GroupMember Where UserorGroupId IN (Select Id From User Where IsActive = TRUE)
```

Below is a snip for the same in dataloader.

[image]

Hope this helps!!